# Unexpected function trigger in angular2 attr.class

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a function to return the class name based on the value. To check the function calling count added the counter and console log.

> ts

```
   count: number = 0;
   myColDiv(month) {
        this.count++;
        console.log('Start',this.count);
        return "col-"+month;
    }
```

> html

```
<div [attr.class]="myColDiv(month)"></div>
```

calling too many times 
counter values reached more than 100 also on page click triggering this function and increases the counter, don't know how come this function triggers.

```
<div (click)="myColDiv(month)"></div>
```

Checked on click only triggers while clicking the div only.
Used primeng components also in my app.

Comment: Binding to methods is discouraged, because the method will be called every time change detection is run. If the method returns new object instances for subsequent call, you'll even get an error like "Expression has changed since it was last checked". Instead assign the value to a property and bind to this property.

Comment: Yeah sure, I am going to use this function for multiple placel, If I bind to property the value will get changed every where, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: myColDiv function will be used (called) from many places, if i bind the css class value to property instead of returning the value, if the property value changes will it affect in every where right? am i wrong?

Comment: I guess I know what you mean. You would need to create a property for every place where you use it. In case of months, you can create an array with 12 values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you assign a class to an element.

Change the logic of your `myColDiv` method to save the result on `this.myColDivClass` in your Controller. After that change your `div` where you want to apply the class to the following:

```html
<div [ngClass]="[myColDivClass]"></div>
```

Comment: There is no need for `[]` around `myColDivClass`

Comment: True. I am just used to always including the brackets just in case I need to add another one later and I was prone to forget the brackets after that.

Comment: [ngClass]="countVal()" tried though calling multiple times.

Comment: Do not bind it to a method. Bind to a value instead as I described in my answer.